# How to remove selected file name at input type=“file” by function in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm using below code to attach file from folder,

```
   <input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
```

After selecting specific file the UI looks like the attached image[image]

Now i'm trying to remove the selected file name with the default text "No file chosen" next of Choose File button like this image, when clicking some button[image]

Can anyone suggest me an idea to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just reset the value to empty for that element. Like below -

```
<input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
<button type="button" (click)="reset(fileInput)">Reset</button>

reset(element) {
    element.value = "";
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-reset?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Perfectly Working! Thank you.

Comment: alternatively we can do another method to avid the reset button

**************
mainfunction($event.taget.value) {
//Upload function logics here
event.target.value = ''
    });
  }
********************
like this you can reset after the upload functions was done

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewChild for this.

In your .ts declare viewchild like this =>

```
@ViewChild('fileInput')
  myVar1: any;
```

Inside reset method you can do like this =>

```
this.myVar1.nativeElement.value = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

this is actually nothing with angular. It can be done with or without angular.

with Angular

```
<input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.value=''">Reset</button>
```

With JQuery

```
$('#fileId').value=''
```

with Pure JS

```
document.GetElementById('elementId').value = '';
```

Comment: Bro dont mix jQuery with Angular, when we have way with angular

Comment: sure, I just wanted to point out that it is actually nothing more then DOM manipulation. but thank you